# 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <' on Login Form

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In my NextJS app.I'm developing a login page and now I'm getting the following error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

This was not appearing before and it started appearing yesterday.I googled the error message and browsed through many SO answers but none of them were helpful.I removed all form related `onSubmit` and `onChange` code but the error is still there.Since which code causes this error,I will post entire `Login` component here.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Heading from '../components/Heading';

class Login extends Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChangeInput = this.onChangeInput.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        date: new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10),
        username: '',
        password: ''
    }
}

onChangeInput(e) {

    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
}

onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const t = {
        date: new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10),
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password
    }
    fetch('/server', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}, 
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
    })

    this.setState({
        username: '',
        password: ''
    });
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <div style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
                <h1>PackMasters Ceylon (Pvt) Ltd</h1>
                <h2>Inventory Management System</h2>
                <h3>Login</h3>
            </div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} onChange={this.onChangeInput} className={"col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"}>
            <Heading title="Login | PackMasters Ceylon (Pvt) Ltd" />
            <div className={"form-group"}>
                <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" value={this.state.username} className={"form-control"} id="username"/>
            </div>
            <div className={"form-group"}>
                <label htmlFor="passsword">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" value={this.state.password} className={"form-control"} id="password" />
            </div>
            <div className={"form-group"}>
                <input type="submit" className={"form-control"} value="Log In"/>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: Hi, is that close bracket valid in (Pvt)? I mean doesn't that mean the close of return()? Just guessing ;)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this code. Are you sure this is what's generating the error? If you could provide the line on which the error is being thrown it would help.

Comment: This usually happens with` fetch`... There is nothing wrong with the code you posted... if there is any data fetching post that part here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling a lot, I found out that it is caused by the browser cache.The problem was solved after clearing browser cache on Chrome.Still I'm not able to explain the exact reason for that.However I will mention here how to clear cache on Google Chrome.

1. On your computer, open Chrome.
2. At the top right, click More.
3. Click More tools > Clear browsing data.
4. At the top, choose a time range. To delete everything, select All time.
5. Next to "Cookies and other site data" and "Cached images and files," check the boxes.
6. Click Clear data

Comment: Having same issue. But this didn't fix for me.

Comment: A multitude of reasons cause this cryptic error and it's really hard to say exactly what has caused yours. I solved my problem with this solution accidentally, after trying a couple dozen of SO solutions :(

Comment: Yup. In my case I found that I had implemented authentication. That blocked static resources as well.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

1. The change handler should go on each input, not on the form
2. A bad idea to set the timestamp in the constructor... Seems you were already going in the right direction...
3. If you convert the handlers into arrow functions (no this context) no need to bind in the constructor (*that's just a side note...*)

Try this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Heading from '../components/Heading';

class Login extends Component {
  state = { username: '', password: '' };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user = {
      date: new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10),
      username: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password,
    };
    fetch('/server', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(user),
    });

    this.setState({ username: '', password: '' });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
          <h1>PackMasters Ceylon (Pvt) Ltd</h1>
          <h2>Inventory Management System</h2>
          <h3>Login</h3>
        </div>
        <form
          onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          className={'col-md-4 col-md-offset-4'}
        >
          <Heading title="Login | PackMasters Ceylon (Pvt) Ltd" />
          <div className={'form-group'}>
            <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="username"
              value={this.state.username}
              className={'form-control'}
              id="username"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={'form-group'}>
            <label htmlFor="passsword">Password</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              value={this.state.password}
              className={'form-control'}
              id="password"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={'form-group'}>
            <input type="submit" className={'form-control'} value="Log In" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Edit: Add a then and a catch block to fetch:

```
fetch('/server', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify(user),
}).then(res => res.json())
  .then(response => console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response)))
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

Also, I noticed you are using Next.js... You need to install `Isomorphic Unfetch` https://github.com/developit/unfetch/tree/master/packages/isomorphic-unfetch

Comment: @pavindu The error is thrown when you click on submit?

Comment: @pavindu also, I noticed you're using Next.js - did you install `isomorphic-unfetch`... https://github.com/developit/unfetch/tree/master/packages/isomorphic-unfetch

Answer (score 0):

In my case, static files were not being served due to global authentication enabled. which was also authenticating static files. So I had to apply `@Public()` metadata to that route to allow into JwtAuthGuard.

```
  @Public()
  @Get('/_next/static/*')
  async getStaticContent(
    @Req() req: IncomingMessage,
    @Res() res: ServerResponse,
  ) {
    await this.appService.handler(req, res);
  }
```

More details on public metadata below.

https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#enable-authentication-globally

Answer (score -1):

And make sure your **"esversion":6** is **6** for that follow below flow

For Mac VSCode : Code(Left top corner) => Prefrences => Settings => USER SETTINGS. and check at right side and write below Code

```
{
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
  "git.ignoreMissingGitWarning": true,
  "window.zoomLevel": 0,
  // you want to write below code for that
  "jshint.options": {
      "esversion":6
  },
}
```